# How do I snake this tub drain?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, drain, clog

I have a Trip Lever Plunger Style Stopper. I removed the faceplate and there was no plunger attached to it or in the pipe, and it seems like the stopper closed. Why i say this is because when we insert a snake or grabber it just comes up through the overflow/ faceplate. I thought i got it to go past that hole but then it hits something solid and wont keep going. When i insert the snake or hair grabber through the faceplate it his something solid and wont move. I have no access panel. How can I snake this drain?

[image]

Comment: To retrieve the disconnected portion of the linkage, you can try using a coat-hanger with a small u-shaped bend on the end. Good luck.

Comment: I dont think it in there lol

Comment: The stopper is apparently lodged in the vertical pipe that is the continuation of the overflow, but below where the horizontal drain comes in. If you can't snag it with something and pull it up to reattach a connecting rod or chain, you will need to cut yourself an access to the piping from behind or below.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a different tool to get the plunger and/or linkage - your drain snake would be unlikely to get it. You might have one of these grabber tools somewhere in the house, and it would be worth trying it (down the access plate opening, so it's got a straight shot at the plug.) If that fails, you're probably near the tipping point where calling a plumber might be quicker and cheaper than continued DIY.

[image: One version of tub drain] [image: Grabber overal][image: Grabber business end]